# Does this array-based data structure have a name?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, terminology

I've been doing a lot of work with a particular data structure which I mainly use as an index for items in a plane tree structure. It consists of an array of positive integers (or bytes, or longs or whatever), each considered to be at 'depth' equal to its index in the array.

Thinking of it as an index within a tree, the root of the tree has an empty array as its index, and the Nth subnode of a given node with index `{a, b... c}` has index `{a, b... c, N}`.

Common operations on it increment/decrement the last number in the array, remove some number of elements from the front or from the back, and append some number of elements to the front or back. In the tree index context, these correspond to stepping forwards/backwards through sibling nodes, finding the index within a subtree or finding the index of a parent node, finding the index when the tree's root is stuck to another tree and finding the index of some descendant node respectively.

Though I initially used them just as indices, I keep discovering new ways to use them for purposes ranging from speeding up data serialization to making code more readable. This has led me to wonder, is this data structure or something like it something that is commonly in use elsewhere? If so, does it have a name? I'm interested in seeing what else I may be able to do with this.

(Sample implementation in C#, with error checking left out to keep things readable)

```
class TreeIndex
{
    public readonly int depth
    {
        get
        {
            return widths.Length;
        }
    }
    public readonly int[] widths;

    public TreeIndex()
    {
        widths = new int[0];
    }
    public TreeIndex(params int[] indices)
    {
        widths = indices;
    }
    public static implicit operator int(TagIndex ti)
    {
        return ti[ti.depth - 1];
    }
    public static operator TagIndex +(TagIndex ti, int i)
    {
        int[] newwidths = ti.widths.Clone();
        newwidths[newwidths.Length - 1] += i;
        return new TagIndex(newwidths);
    }
    public static operator TagIndex -(TagIndex ti, int i) { return ti + (-i); }
    public static operator TagIndex <<(TagIndex ti, int i)
    {
        int[] newwidths = new int[ti.depth - i];
        Array.Copy(ti.widths, newwidths, ti.depth - i);
        return new TagIndex(newwidths);
    }
    public static operator TagIndex >>(TagIndex ti, int i)
    {
        int newwidths = new int[ti.depth - i];
        Array.Copy(ti.widths, i, newwidths, 0, ti.depth - i);
        return new TagIndex(newwidths);
    }
    public static operator TagIndex ^(TagIndex tia, TagIndex tib) 
    {
        int newwidths = new int[tia.depth + tib.depth];
        Array.Copy(tia.widths, newwidths, tia.depth);
        Array.Copy(tib.widths, 0, newwidths, tia.depth, tib.depth);
        return new TagIndex(newwidths);
    }
}
```

Comment: Despite the overloaded operators and the specific use case, as a data structure, this is really just a list.

Comment: Is that so? I'm not really clear on what constitutes a distinct data structure I suppose. I've seen a number of similar questions that seem to define them in terms of operations rather than exclusively by content, is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The comment is correct: it's just a list.

Consider the [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class. You can increase or decrease its capacity (analogous to your `-` and `+` operators) by setting the `Capacity` property. You can add items to the end of the list by calling `AddRange`. You can insert items anywhere in the list by calling `InsertRange`. Removing items is a matter of calling `RemoveRange`.

Your `^` operator is a simple matter of:

```
list1.AddRange(list2);
```

`List<T>` does everything your data structure does, and more besides, including implementing all of the common collection interfaces: `IList`, `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`, etc. It's a common data structure that every .NET programmer is familiar with. If you ever envision others working on your code, you would be well advised to use `List<T>` rather than rolling your own custom class with non-standard semantics and crazy overloads that nobody else is familiar with.

Comment: Just for reference, most of the work I do with this structure is not in C#. I chose a C# implementation for my example because it takes much less work to remove the error checking in C# than it does to remove the memory management from my C implementation. As far as Lists/Interfaces go, while I understand that in cases where code is likely to be used, managed and extended by many people, the benefit of familiarity and clarity far outstrips the minor performance hit incurred, when I write code for my own, performance intensive use I tend to prefer a customized solution.

Comment: @P...: Understood. C# isn't the only language with such a data structure. Java's `ArrayList` has similar capabilities, as do Python, Javascript, and, I think, PHP. Likely every modern language has an analog.

Comment: Looking more at examples of things commonly called 'data structures', I must ask for more clarification on how distinct something must be to qualify. By similar arguments to those you use above, you can say that a list of ints, an array of ints and a single int are all the same data structure, just with less and less functionality as you progress.

Comment: @P...: I disagree. There are fundamental differences between a primitive type and an array of that type. And a dynamic array of that type adds yet another level of functionality that I think makes it a different data type. But you're right in that at least the last two are examples of the abstract data type we call a Collection. Or a list. Your index is simply a specialization of a common dynamic array or list. I'm not saying that it's bad or good, but rather that it's a subset of functionality that is commonly available in most modern programming languages.

Comment: @JimMischel  Unfortunately he said "C implementation" and in C if you want a list you have to make your own.  I would be interested to see how the C implementation is used since C doesn't have operator overloads...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: The original question didn't say "C implementation." In fact, his sample is C#. Regardless, it's easy enough to create a dynamic list in C, which has the same basic semantics as the C# implementation. As for the operator overloading, I view it as inappropriate for this data structure, regardless of the language.